# Awk pattern matching on output not input

Tags: awk

I'm using `awk` to output relevant live data from my Apache logs like so:

`tail -f access_log | awk '{print $9, $1, $4, $7}';`

Works great but it outputs all the images, CSS, etc too. So I'd like to restrict output to only HTML pages. If I use `awk '/.html/ {print $9, $1, $4, $7}';` it still matches almost all lines in the logfile because the referrer includes ".html". My output doesn't have the referrer though, so is there a way to get `awk` to match in my output only, not the input?

Comment: please show sample data that illustrates your issue. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that field 7 contains the URL you're interested in, use

```
awk '$7 ~ /\.html/ {print <your-field-list>}'
```

I think the right field number depends on the format of your log file. I could be wrong.

That tells awk to print your field list only if the seventh field matches a literal dot followed by "html".

Answer (score 0):

```
... | awk '
{ 
  output = $9 OFS $1 OFS $4 OFS $7
  if (output ~ /.html/) print output
}'
```